# How to separate data into two tables with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

Now I have two tables, the first table called **StudentBase** and has three columns: **id**, **firstname** and **lastname**. The second table called **ResearchAssistant** and has two columns: **id** and **course**. I designed the tables like this because there are different kinds of students and research assistant is one of them. The two table could be joint together with the primary key **id**.

I'm writing an endpoint **/researchAssistant** and take following content as request body of **POST** method.

```
{
    "firstname":"Jack",
    "lastname":"Peter",
    "course":"MATH"
}
```

What I want is that saving **firstname** and **lastname** into **StudentBase** table and save **course** into **ResearchAssistant** table. And generate a same **id** for both.

The first idea comes to my mind is building 3 model classes: **StudentBase**(id, firstname, lastname), **ResearchAssistant**(id, course) and **ResearchAssistantMixed**(firstname, lastname, course). I use **ResearchAssistantMixed** class as the request body class. After getting the data I will seperate it into a new **StudentBase** object and a **ResearchAssistant** object, then I store them seperately.

This process seems really stupid and the performance should be quite low. Do you have some better ideas? How does Spring Boot deal with such cases? Thank you!

Comment: It would be possible in plain SQL.

Comment: Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name could you please provide more details? Or some documents? I'm a rookie of db designing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a database problem and not a spring-boot problem. This is how I would approach (I'm assuming you're using some relational DB like MySql and hibernate for ORM):

Database Tables:

```
student_base
    - id (primary key)
    - first_name
    _ last_name

research_assistant
    - id (primary key)
    - student_base_id (foreign key referencing id of student_base)
    - course
```

You can now have equivalent entity classes in Java (for hibernate):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student_base")
public class StudentBase {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    // getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "research_assistant")
public class ResearchAssistant {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_base_id")
    private StudentBase studentBase;

    @Column(name = "course")
    private String course;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Now in your DAOs, you don't need to do much, just persist a student_base record and use the returned object to persist a research_assistant record. For example:

```
StudentBase studentBase = persist(new StudentBase(1, "abc", "xyz");
persist(new ResearchAssistant(1, studentBase, "pqr");
```

You can (and should) have two separate classes to accept the request object of the post API (don't use entity classes to accept request data).